# bind()-ing UDP sockets to different addresses

Tags: c, sockets, udp, bind

I have a very simple question that I cannot seem to find an answer for anywhere:

Using Linux C sockets, is it possible to bind() and then recvfrom() UDP packets on an IP address other than the local address?

i.e, if a host has been given the LAN address 10.0.0.4, and I want it to be able to receive UDP packets sent to the address 10.0.0.5 on port 5505 (for example) how would this be achieved?

I simply cannot find any examples of this use of bind/recvfrom, which seems like it should be quite commonplace.

**Update**

I am trying to communicate packet streams between multiple hosts. Each host streams UDP packets on its own address, and any of the other hosts can listen in by recvfrom()ing on a specific address.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here... What is the flow of traffic here? Who is sending? Who is reading? You got a machine in the middle?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using multicast addresses for that?

Comment: Multicast or even local broadcast.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't generally bind to a non-local unicast address.  On an Ethernet, such packets would be addressed to the hardware address of the owner of that IP address, and by default you NIC won't even forward such packets to your kernel.

You can achieve the effect you want by using IP Multicast.  You would pick a particular multicast address for your application and bind to that, and then use the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` socket option to join the multicast group.  You can then use `recvfrom()` in the usual way.